# Powershell Comparing 2 Object arrays based on Properties of the Objects inside without losing the Format

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, format

I have a problem where i need to compare 2 PSObject arrays based on a property of the objects inside and i cant lose the format of the data in $neudaten.

Im trying to achieve this for now 5 hours and i can smell the victory by it wont let me touch it xD

Would be nice if u could help

```
$neudaten = Get-Content -Path $neudatenpf  | Select-Object  -skip 1 |`
            ConvertFrom-Csv  `
                -Delimiter ";"`
                -Header $categoriesCSV

$neudaten = $neudaten | Where-Object  -Property ID  -NE $useralt.ID
```

Comment: have you tried the `Compare-Object` cmdlet yet? it can compare collections ...

Comment: yes but apperently im to dumb to use it without breaking my Format bc if i compare with -property it only pipes out the compared property + the side indicator

Comment: If `$useralt` is a _PSObject_ use `$neudaten | Where-Object { $_.ID  -NE $useralt.ID}` or if `$useralt` is a _collection_ of such objects use `$neudaten | Where-Object { $_.ID  -NotIn $useralt.ID}` or `$neudaten | Where-Object { -not ($_.ID  -in $useralt.ID) }`. You should always provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ItsOswin - so ... PLEASE do as so often recommended ... provide the code you tried and how it failed to meet your needs. [*grin*]